# What does the X mean over my crosshair in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes an "X" appears over my crosshair when I'm firing at an enemy with a gun or a tank. Does that mean that I have hit the enemy, I'm hitting it, or that I will hit it if I fire now?

[image: battlefield 3 crosshair hit indicator]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that you have hit the enemy.  This is especially important when firing rockets at enemy vehicles, since frequently after you fire you have to hide to avoid dying so you can't see if you got a hit.

It does *not* mean, however, that you have disabled or destroyed a vehicle, so also be alert for the "vehicle disabled" and "vehicle destroyed" notifications coming up on your screen

Comment: It is also important while sniping from longer distances, where you cannot exactly see if it was a hit or not.

Comment: It's called a hit-marker. Just notification that you did in fact hit what you were aiming at. Also, a source of frustration when you get 5 of them and someone runs away. =)

Comment: To add to Bora's comment, when sniping with bolt-action rifles, holding down the fire-key allows you to remain scoped in to see what it lands. (Unnecessary if you equip the "Straight Pull Bolt" accessory.)